# Action format in activity feed doesn't make sense

Tags: facebook, action

I have an action that states a user has placed an order. Similar to `user_name has placed an order on app_name`. This shows perfect in activity but in recent activity it shows `user_name placed og:title on app_name`.

My Action is `Place` and my object is `order`.

```
  <meta property="fb:app_id" content="app id" />
  <meta property="og:type" content="joestakeaways:order" />
  <meta property="og:image" content="http://server.com/path/to/icon.jpg" />
  <meta property="og:title" content="Joe takeaway" />
  <meta property="og:url" content="http://server.com" />
  <meta property="og:description" content="For the best fish and chips in town try Joe&#039;s Takeaways!" />
```

Any way to make the recent activity show the same as actual activity. I could change the `og:title` to `an order` but then that looks a bit weird on the other feed.

[image: correct]

[image: not Correct]

Comment: Why not use 'order' or a variation of that as the verb?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The execution of this action is not in the way intended. While I figure out a better way I have changed the `title` to Online order and added

```
  <meta property="og:determiner" content="an" />
```

Not great but better

Answer (score 0):

You are not really using it as it's intended. You actually want a place or an arbitrary order. But the Open Graph was meant for a specific instance of your object.

Your action is ordering (placing an order).
Your *type* of object is an order.
A specific instance of order is "1 Portion of Fries with Fish"

i.e. `<meta property="og:title" content="Joe takeaway" />`

So if you want to keep the object arbitrary you should change the title to reflect an actual object of type order.

```
<meta property="og:title" content="An order on Joe takeaway" />
```

Which will result in

> User placed an order on Joe's Takeaways
>   16 minutes ago
>   An order on Joe takeaway
>   For the best fish and chips ...

And for the activity

> User placed An order on Joe's takeaway on Joe's Takeaways.

It's still repetitive, shows capital A (because it should be an actual name of an object) but it's a better match (in my opinion).

Comment: Your right, I am not really using it as intended. The correct result would be the order and it's contents which would be a bit weird. While I figure out a better way I have changed the title to `Online order` and added `<meta property="og:determiner" content="an" />`. Not great but better